# What is 'Duplicate key value specified.' error in AS/400 -SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

When I ran the below query in AS/400 - SQL , I get an error called 'Duplicate key value specified.'

```
update Table1                            
set Field1 = '0'                         
where Field0 = '0' and Field1 = '8888888'
```

Can someone please tell me what am I missing?

Here is how the table goes?
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6d7Q.png)

Comment: There is probably a unique index on `field1` and already another record with value `0`

Comment: @ juergen d, Thanks for replying.

Couldn't understand what you meant by 'index'?

Comment: I've posted table, please be kind and look.

Comment: Just a little tip: Looks like you are just learning SQL. In that case I would recommend an easier SQL engine like MySQL for instance. There are way better sql engines than DB2.

Comment: It depends both on the table structure and data already present in the table. Can you share *both* table creation script (or DDSs) *and* data in the table before issueing the command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your field1 column has the primary key constraint. And if you try to update the field with the value which is already present in the table then it will give you the.

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "test1_pkey"
  Detail: Key (field0)=(1) already exists.
```

I have reproduced the issue with the help of following steps:

1. create table test1(field0 varchar(30) primary key, field1 varchar(30));
2. insert into test1 values('0','10');
3. insert into test1 values('1','10');
4. update test1 set field0 = '1' where field1='10' and field0='0';

Comment: Thanks for replying.

Here's what I'm trying to do=> 

At the beginning, both fields were full of '8's. I  just want to update both field0 and field1 with '0'. But when I ran the query for both of them it gave the same  'Duplicate key value specified' error.


Then what I did was ran the query only for field0. It was successful. Rows were updated.

Comment: can you share the table schema? That will help us to understand more.

Comment: try-  show create table test1;  //here test1 is table name

Comment: "show create table test1" wont work in AS/400 SQL. If to find the correct command, what do I have to search?

Comment: Maybe you can try- DESCRIBE TABLE tableName.  command. Or you can refer this [link](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-view-the-definition-of-a-table-in-ibm-db2/) for more detail.

Comment: Its a file actually, I've tried what you have mentioned but couldn't get file information